# MySQL query to select both greater than and less than value

Tags: php, mysql

mytable

```
id        name    
-------   --------
1         James
2         John
3         Edward
4         Bill
```

above is my table, I'm trying to build a query which can select both the greater than and less than value. For example `$current_id = 3`, so what I need to select is `2` and `4` from the table with a single query. I can obtain the one(less than or greater than) value but not sure how to combine the query to obtain both.

Query

```
SELECT mytable.id FROM mytable WHERE id > $current_id;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(SELECT id 
FROM mytable 
WHERE id > $current_id
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 1)
UNION 
(SELECT id 
FROM mytable 
WHERE id < $current_id
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: You need to add brackets around the individual queries to use a limit AND a Union.

Comment: He is asking(not clearly) for previous and next records only

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT mytable.id FROM mytable
WHERE id = $current_id +1
OR id=$current_id -1;
```

Here we are using OR gate that will check both conditions and it will run both conditions, if both are passing then it will show the result of both conditions or if any one conditions is passing then it will show the result only of that condition that is passing.

Comment: You're assuming that the `id` of each record is consecutive. If any rows have been deleted the `id` fields won't be consecutive and this will fail.